# Proving the connection between limit points and neighborhoods

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove the following proposition stated in my general topology textbook:

> Let $A$ be a subset of a topological space $(X ,\tau).$ A point $x \in X$ is a limit point of $A$ if and only if every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $A$ different than $x$.

So, I already proved that if $x$ is a limit point of $A$, then every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $A$ different than $x$, But I'm having trouble proving that the other way is also true.

---

**My approach:**

Let's assume that every neighbourhood of $x$ contains a point of $A$ different than $X$.

Let $N$ be a neighbourhood of $x$, then:

$$\exists U\in \tau:x \in U \subseteq B$$

We do know that $\exists a \in A: a\neq x \wedge a \in B$. But that does not imply that $a \in U$, making $x$ a limit point.

How can I prove this?

Comment: $U$ is also a nbhd of $x$.

Comment: how do you define a limit point?

Comment: A point $p$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if for every open set $U$ such that $p \in U$,  $\exists a \in A$ such that $a \neq p \wedge a \in U$ @rarwoan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of neighborhood, any open set $U$ containing $x$ is a neighborhood of $x$. Which trivially proves the converse.